# which function can be used for verifying hashes in RandomX

Tags: hash-verification, mining-technical-details

greetings need help unable to find function for light mode verification for hashes in RandomX source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Light mode" just means don't alloc and init a 2080 MiB `randomx_dataset` (just use a `randomx_cache`, which is 256 MiB). So don't use the flag `RANDOMX_FLAG_FULL_MEM` when calling [randomx_create_vm](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/1c603a23fa0004615b4f2d42ad95f2693f16093b/src/randomx.h#L177-L202) and pass it a NULL dataset.

Whether you are mining or verifying, you call the same `randomx_calculate_hash` function.