# How light mode maintains memory time product

Tags: mining-technical-details

How does exactly light mode in RX maintains memory time product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full mode (fast) is fast because the full dataset is generated up-front, i.e. the full ~2G dataset is generated, in memory, beforehand.

Light mode (slow) is slow because the dataset *items* will be generated on the fly (as they are needed).

When mining, you want to create hashes as fast as possible. You'll be changing the *message* (the input being hashed, e.g. changing the nonce), but don't want to be creating dataset items on the fly, because this will slow you down. Hence *light mode* is useless for mining (it runs much slower because it has to generate dataset items on the go), but useful for verification only purposes (where absolute speed is of less importance).

Comment: Which function does that

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/14076/7493

Comment: Not that function function, the function in light mode which creates dataset on the fly

Comment: https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/102f8acf90a7649ada410de5499a7ec62e49e1da/src/dataset.cpp#L164